# Initialize local variables async

Tags: c#, async-await

Using the async functionality available in .Net 4.5+, <strike>is there a way to initialize multiple local variables concurrently, without having to do it in two steps?</strike> is there another way to delay blocking the parent until an awaited variable is attempted to be dereferenced?

Example: I have a method in which I am given three IDs which are used to fetch objects from three separate services. Each service will take a non-trivial amount of time to return and I would like to minimize the clock time needed. There is no interdependency on the objects creation.

What I can do:

```
string MyFunc(long userId, long moduleId, long targetId) {
    var userTask = _userRepo.Get(userId);
    var moduleTask = _moduleRepo.Get(moduleId);
    var targetTask = _targetRepo.Get(targetId);

    var user = await userTask;
    var module = await moduleTask;

    var action = module.GetActionFor(user);

    var target = await targetTask;
    action.ApplyTo(target);

    return string.Format("{0} begins {1} at {2}",
        user.Name,
        action.Description,
        target.Location);
}
```

What can be done to remove the intermediary <strike>Tasks</strike> task variables?

### Clarification:

I am looking for something more concise. I do not need the Tasks aside from the initial assignment and the results are used multiple times in the remainder of the operation.

Doing this results in essentially running the code synchronously. If each Get statement takes 1 second to return, the block takes 3 seconds to complete:

```
var user = await _userRepo.Get(userId);
var module = await _moduleRepo.Get(moduleId);
var target = await _targetRepo.Get(targetId);
```

Doing the following results in the code becoming hard to read, especially when the objects need to be used multiple times:

```
var user = _userRepo.Get(userId);
var module = _moduleRepo.Get(moduleId);
var target = _targetRepo.Get(targetId);

var action = (await module).GetActionFor(await user);
action.ApplyTo(await target);

var formattedString = string.Format("{0} begins {1} at {2}",
        (await user).Name,
        action.Description,
        (await target).Location);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Other than querying the database concurrently using `Task.WhenAll`, I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: There aren't any *intermediary* tasks in your code. `await` doesn't create an intermediary task, it awaits for an existing one to finish. Is perhaps the actual question "How do I await for multiple tasks to finish?"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose by _intermediary tasks_, I meant _intermediary variables_. I know to use `Task.WhenAll` to await multiple tasks, so the question is not about waiting for multiple tasks to finish. More what I'm looking for is something like SCOOP in Eiffel -- a way to auto-await the `Task.Result` when the variable is first dereferenced. It seems a shame that the second code block would yield and block before the next statement rather than waiting until an awaited variable is dereferenced to yield.

Comment: Is this for logging? (It sort of looks like a log/trace/debug line of code)...  If so, might I suggest, rather than return the line from the task and deal with the potential continuation hassles, etc, why not just sink the string as a message via some kind of event mediator logic? For instance, the `EventAggregator` comes out-of-the-box well equipped for this need. Your async code could just publish the event & payload string in the last line rather than returning the string. Within the event handler, you can then focus on a good approach for the data that's coming in asynchronously.

Comment: @code4life The code above is contrived for for example only. I can see how it may look like logging code. If being more concrete would help, the actual code base is aggregating microservice actions/responses and database fetches/updates. Trying to post a working example would run long even for a CodeReview post.

Comment: Then just toss those responses into a `concurrent priority queue`, and when everything's done, dequeue everything. Or dequeue anytime 1 or more elements are found (would need a separate thread for that). Would that work? BTW, the CQP can be found in the Parallels Extension Extras github: https://github.com/slashdotdash/ParallelExtensionsExtras

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a good way to get exactly what you want (at least not without some serious compile-time meta-programming).

The closest I could figure out is:

```
User user = null;
Module module = null;
Target target = null;

await RunAll(
    async () => user = await _userRepo.Get(userId),
    async () => module = await _moduleRepo.Get(moduleId),
    async () => target = await _targetRepo.Get(targetId));

var action = module.GetActionFor(user);
action.ApplyTo(target);

var formattedString = string.Format("{0} begins {1} at {2}",
        user.Name,
        action.Description,
        target.Location);
```

Where `RunAll()` is defined like this:

```
static Task RunAll(params Func<Task>[] funcs)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(funcs.Select(f => f()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each `Task` instance has the same generic type parameter (for example, `Task<object>`), then you can do it all in one line:

```
object[] results = await Task.WhenAll<object>(_userRepo.Get(userId), 
                                              _moduleRepo.Get(moduleId), 
                                              _targetRepo.Get(targetId));

return string.Format("{0} begins {1} at {2}",
                     ((User)results [0]).Name,
                     ((Module)results [1]).Description,
                     ((Target)results [2]).Location);
```

According to [MSDN - Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed

Comment: Umm, No: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object[]'`

Comment: @psaxton See edit. Try calling `Task.WhenAll<object>(...)`. Be aware that all input tasks must return a `Task<object>`

Comment: 'A' for effort, but changing repos to return `object` doesn't seem to be the right way to go. Writing wrapper methods to cast the result wouldn't be any better.